# OSCommerce rror: Backup directory does not exist. , please create it and/or set location in configure.php

Tags: directory, backup

I have a problem in OScommerce database backup manager directory folder.

I tried 777, 755, 775 but still the same error, it says Error: Backup directory does not exist. , please create it and/or set location in configure.php.

The folder was there and also in the config file:
define('DIR_FS_BACKUP', DIR_FS_ADMIN . 'db_backup/');

Any possible ideas why it happened everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Someone from oscommerce forum just helped me out:

This solved the problem:
in the admin/includes/configure.php

write this define:

**define('DIR_FS_ADMIN', '/home/"servernamehere"/public_html/admin/');**